# float2Int behavior for border case

Tags: haskell, ghc

`float2Int` seems to overflow somewhere between `2^^62` and `2^^63` for 64-bit machines (I tried it on intel iMac with GHC 7.6.1). I just noticed this issue when trying to check the `maxBound` for `Int`. `float2Int` is implemented as a primop `float2Int#` in GHC.

GHCi Prompt output is below - `maxBound::Int` is `2^^63` on my intel mac. I also tried casting `2^^63` to `Float`, and then reducing the values a bit to see if the overflow goes away (to account for small rounding errors if any). It doesn't:

```
λ: maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
λ: GHC.Float.float2Int $ 2^^63 -- overflows
-9223372036854775808
λ: GHC.Float.float2Int $ (9223372036854775807::Float) -- now try actual value of 2^^63
-9223372036854775808
λ: GHC.Float.float2Int $ (9223372036854000000::Float)  -- reduce it a bit
-9223372036854775808
λ: minBound :: Int -- overflow value is same as minBound::Int
-9223372036854775808
λ: GHC.Float.float2Int $  2^^62 + 2^^61 -- works fine here
6917529027641081856
```

Is this overflow on 64-bit Int boundary an expected behavior? It seems to work fine until `2^^62`, and overflows somewhere between `2^^62` and `2^^63`. I looked up GHC trac to see if there were any reported bugs, and didn't find any. I didn't find any posts on SO either about this one.

Comment: <irrelevant>A number theorist once said to me that people feel that big numbers are like small numbers, only bigger, but that they really really aren't.</irrelevant>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is all correct behavior.  First, lets clear up a minor detail:

> maxBound::Int is 2^^63 on my intel mac

No, it should be `(2^63) - 1`.  That minus one is very important so `float2Int (2^^63)` should overflow.

Now how about your reductions?  Consider this:

```
Prelude GHC.Float.RealFracMethods> let a = 9223372036854775807::Float
Prelude GHC.Float.RealFracMethods> let b = 9223372036854000000::Float
Prelude GHC.Float.RealFracMethods> a == b
True
```

Floats are approximations and your reduction has not cause a material change in the Float.  The inputs so far are all equal to `2^63`.

Finally,

```
> 2^^62 + 2^^61 < (2^^63 :: Float)
True
```

With your last test you found a number that, when cast as a Float, is represented as something less than `2^63`, thus within the range of a 64 bit `Int` and resulting in your expected value.

Comment: @thomas-m-dubuisson, good point about using float equality to check for rounding error.